SalesForceConnector-Response header for Salesforce api
From PowerAutomate while using  Get Records action with 'LastModifiedDate' filter,
some records are missing in the output of Power Automate 'Get Records' action even though they fall within the specified date range. Currently there is no Id logged to provide to Salesforce to identify the issue.While using SalesforceConnector 'Get Records' action in PowerAutomate does anyone have an idea as to which response header from salesforce api
has the ID that we should log so that we can provide Salesforce the ID to help to check on an issue.
